# Python / Django multi-tenancy solution

Tags: python, django, multi-tenant

I could use some help creating a plan of attack for a project I'm working on.

Imagine that the site is for a group that oversees regional sales offices, distributed around the world. The purpose of this project is to let superusers spin up a new sub-site specific to each and every office, at a fast pace -- sites are added on a frequent basis. The office sub-sites should be wholly contained with "admin" users specific to that sub-site and should be user-friendly CMS. A superuser should be able to step in and manage all of these office sub-sites.

In addition to the self-contained office sub-site instance, there is also a need for each sub-site to manage contacts, leads, etc and store this in one central area for the superusers.

I've done a few sites using Django, but never anything multi-tenant. I'd like suggestions for technologies to use or tutorials/documentation that might be helpful.

Requirements:

1. Each sub-site uses the same source (templates, JS, available features, etc), but can be modified to reflect custom content within the templates.
2. Assigned subdomains (with an option of using a fully qualified domain) per sub-site, configured within the project, not in a hardcoded settings file.
3. Sub-site specific user access controls, in addition to superusers who can access all sub-sites.
4. The ability to provide an "independent" CMS for each sub-site. i.e., A sub-site admin only sees their content. My preference for this project would be django-cms, but I'm open to suggestions.
5. Support for apps that pool the data from all the sub-sites, but limit sub-site "admins" to  only viewing their records into that app.

Considering the above, what approach would you recommend? I am open to reconsidering technologies, but I would like to stick with Python.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There is a great app called [django-tenant-schemas](https://github.com/bcarneiro/django-tenant-schemas) that uses PostgreSQL schemas mechanism to create multi-tenancy.

What you get is specyfing `SHARED_APPS` that contain objects shared across all the schemas (sub-sites), and `TENANT_APPS` that contain objects specific for a sub-site, i.e. users, records etc. The schemas are completely isolated from each other.

Each PostgreSQL schema is tied to a domain url, so that middleware checks the `HOST` part of the request and sets the db connection's schema to appriopriate one.

In addition, it allows you to define a `PUBLIC_SCHEMA_URLCONF` which allows you to specify urlconf file for *public* schema - the meta site that is not tied to any sub-site.

Comment: Thanks for a quick answer! I looked into django-tenant-schemas, but the one thing that I got hung up on was that it doesn't seem to offer any help on the auth side of things (which I am not very experienced with). Would it be difficult to create a role or group that could be limited to specific sub-sites?

Comment: If you mean a user group or role that would make it possible for users in this group/role access defined sub-sites, then you would have to either make `SiteUser` models shared across all schemas (i.e. `public` one), that would contain, for each allowed schema, the id of the user model inside schema. Otherwise, you could just make the `User` model shared, and deal with authentication in another middleware/custom auth backend.

Comment: Are there any security risks with django-tenant-schemas?  Could a user view data outside of his schema?

Answer (score 5):

Sorry for quick and dirty answer, i just share what i've done to achieve multi tenancy:

- [django-tenancy](https://github.com/charettes/django-tenancy) I like the author's approach of using "dynamic model"
- [django-dynamicsite](https://bitbucket.org/uysrc/django-dynamicsites) This is where dynamic SITE_ID based on domain will be linked to a tenant

Both libraries above, when combined, is able to serve a django instance which is multi-tenant, and flexible. What i mean flexible here is: you can define *any* model whether is it "tenant" or "global". So, you can have a site with global user but per tenant product catalogue, or per tenant + product. From many django app i've tried, this is the most flexible way to achieve multi tenancy

Answer (score 3):

The Django based CMS [Mezzanine](http://mezzanine.jupo.org/) also has [multi-tenancy support](http://mezzanine.jupo.org/docs/multi-tenancy.html).

It has most of the features you requested except the sub-site user controls I think. The admin page can be separated by site for admin users, but the normal users not.

However, if you dont need a CMS this might be an overkill for your use-case, But I wanted to mention it here for completeness.

Answer (score 0):

I have been trying to use [django-tenants](https://github.com/django-tenants/django-tenants) for a while along with Wagtail but this combination didn't work very well, or let me say, despite of a lot of try I was not able to get wagtail admin-page working correctly.  <strike>I think will try to switch to [django-tenant-schemas](https://github.com/bernardopires/django-tenant-schemas) which I more widely used</strike> .

**NOTE: django-tenant-schemas is not maintained now.**

Comment: django-tenant-schemas is no more maintained .... django-tenants is forked from it and is begin maintained actively... so I would not suggest to move to django-tenant-schemas

Comment: I haven’t worked with Django since 2016, so this entire thread is pretty out of date at this point. Anyone reading this now should look at the “django-multitenant” project on github or at the “Multi-Tenancy in Django” blog post from viget.com